building with meson on msys2 ucrt64 environment, unable to include <epoxy/gl.h>
I'm trying to build a C library that uses epoxy to load on windows using the msys2 ucrt64 environment. In order to build everything I'm using meson:
User@WinDev2401Eval UCRT64 /c/Users/User/github/test-epoxy
$ meson --version
1.4.0

According to the docs using epoxy should be simple, just:
#include <epoxy/gl.h>

And this works perfectly, when building on my ubuntu linux machine. The problems occurs when moving to build my library on Windows in the msys2 ucrt64 environment. In this case the include path isn't found somehow.
I've installed epoxy using the pacboy tool:
$ pacboy -Ss libepoxy:p
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libepoxy 1.5.10-5 [installed]
    A library for handling OpenGL function pointer management for you (mingw-w64)

and I can find the header by hand:
$ ls /ucrt64/include/epoxy/
common.h  egl.h  egl_generated.h  gl.h  gl_generated.h  wgl.h  wgl_generated.h

I've written the small C program that demonstrates the issue:
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
int main () {
   return 0;
}

In order to build I've written the following meson.build script:
project('test-epoxy', 'c',
  version : '0.1',
  default_options : ['warning_level=3'])

epoxy_dep = dependency('epoxy' , version: '>1.0')

executable('test-epoxy',
           'main.c',
           install : true,
           dependencies:[epoxy_dep])

I've tried 2 configurations:
meson setup build
meson setup build-inc --includedir /ucrt64/include/

I think the second is redundant, as -I think that - /ucrt64/include/ should automatically be on the include path, but i've tried it anyway.
The output of the configureation step is:
$ meson setup build-inc --includedir /ucrt64/include/
The Meson build system
Version: 1.4.0
Source dir: C:/Users/User/github/test-epoxy
Build dir: C:/Users/User/github/test-epoxy/build-inc
Build type: native build
Project name: test-epoxy
Project version: 0.1
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 13.2.0 "cc (GCC) 13.2.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.41
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: YES (C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin/pkg-config.EXE) 2.1.0
Run-time dependency epoxy found: YES 1.5.10
Build targets in project: 1

test-epoxy 0.1

  User defined options
    includedir: C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/

Found ninja-1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1 at C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin/ninja.EXE


The configuration works nicely, however, the build fails it seems that /ucrt64/include/ isn't on the include path even after adding it manually.
The output of the build is:
$ ninja -C build-inc/
ninja: Entering directory `build-inc/'
[1/2] Compiling C object test-epoxy.exe.p/main.c.obj
FAILED: test-epoxy.exe.p/main.c.obj
"cc" "-Itest-epoxy.exe.p" "-I." "-I.." "-fdiagnostics-color=always" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-Wall" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wextra" "-Wpedantic" "-O0" "-g" -MD -MQ test-epoxy.exe.p/main.c.obj -MF "test-epoxy.exe.p/main.c.obj.d" -o test-epoxy.exe.p/main.c.obj "-c" ../main.c
../main.c:2:10: fatal error: epoxy/gl.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <epoxy/gl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Perhaps/probably I'm doing something wrong, I currently have limited experience compiling programs on windows. I would love to get some help on compiling using epoxy on windows using msys2  in the ucrt64 environment, help with the other environments would also be nice.

What does which cc say?

I pulled the package on MSYS2's MinGW64 environment and hand-compiled your program (gcc test.c) without any issues.  Try hand-compiling it on ucrt64 perhaps?

@HolyBlackCat $ which cc /usr/bin/cc

@legends2k If run the same in the mingw64 msys2 environment, everything works out. No need to hand-compile, meson produces ninja buildscript that do find epoxy/gl.h

This is wrong, it means you didn't install mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc (and did install gcc, which you don't really need).

I'd rather close as a duplicate of What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?, I already gave a more detailed explanation there.

@hete I suggested hand-compilation as a quick way to test the toolchain's working condition.

@legends2k thanks for your responses too! I see your point. You want to see if just running gcc works and runs the right compiler.
